# Which WebSphere MQ connection attributes are required for JMS connectivity?

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

While establishing connection to WebSphere MQ over JMS  using MQ 7.0 libraries, I am able to set following WMQ-specific connection attributes:

- Hostname
- Port
- Channel
- Queue Manager
- Queue Name
- User ID
- Password

I am pretty sure I would need send things to specific queue, so I believe the Queue Name and Hostname will be always necessary.

Which of the remaining are typically always required while establishing a connection via 
JMS? 
For example, does it make sense to setup WebSphere MQ in such a way, that no Queue Manager or Channels would exist or be necessary to send messages to specific queue?

Is it common for such MQ/JMS setup to not use UserID/Password at all?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depends on the type of connection, `server bindings` or `client bindings`. In `server bindings` the queue manager and application communicate using shared memory and in client bindings, the communication is over sockets.

When using `server bindings` only queue manager name is required for establishing a connection whereas `host name`, `port`, `channel name` are required for `client bindings`.

UserID and Password are optional for MQ JMS. As of v7.5, MQ validates only the UserID and not password. If UserID is not specified, MQ JMS will pass the logged in UserID of the machine to the queue manager. Additional components like `Security Exit` is required for password validation.